# R - have xtable interpret HTML tags within strings as HTML tags rather than literals

Tags: html, r, xtable

Assuming I don't want to or cannot modify the stylesheet or the HTML internally, how can I make xtable interpret a section of a string in R as a html tag rather than a literal? For example, I have:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("<b>Foo</b>", "Bar", "Box"), byrow = TRUE)
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
```

I want "Foo" to be bold. Nevertheless, when xtable creates the table, it prints "<b>Foo</b>" (i.e. it interprets the string literally) rather than "**Foo**". Is there an option or workaround to custom-defining a tag within a string and ensuring that it is interpreted as a tag?

Comment: Do you know about `knitr::kable()` or `formattable()`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to post up an answer for this question, as, after a bit of fidgeting around, I do have a per-se solution.

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("<b>Foo</b>", "Bar", "Box"), byrow = TRUE)
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE, 
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

This works, but can have unintended consequences, since you are overwriting the default santize.text function and it seems that you cannot specify to apply `sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}` as a lambda function for a particular part of the table, but have to instead apply it to the whole table. It works for something simple like this... might not work for everything.